# Flexbox margin-right: auto not working, if I use display:none in one element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I would like remove one item in flexbox with `display:none`, and I would like set align right (with `margin-right: auto`) to `logo` class item, from class `nav`. But if I use `display:none`, then `margin-right: auto` not working. What's wrong? Maybe another solution instead of `display:none`?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: white;
}

/*
---------------------------
----------Flexbox----------
---------------------------
*/

.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 80px;
}

.menubtn {
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
    align-self: center;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.nav {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    transition: .5s;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.closebtn {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-top: 3em;
}



/*
---------------------------
--------Responsive---------
---------------------------
*/

@media (min-width: 640px) {

    .closebtn {
        display: none;
    }

    .menubtn {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav {
        transition: 0;
        background: none;
        color: #000;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        position: static;
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Mineral Fever</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <p class="menubtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</p>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                        <li class="nav-item closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">Termékek</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">Kapcsolat</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">Szállítás</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1 class="logo">Mineral Fever</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have it backwards. If you want to push an element to the right, give it an auto left margin (and vice versa). It might help you to think of it this way: margins (excluding negative ones) push away from something. In this case you want to push an element away from the left edge of its parent. Auto margins increase as needed to take up any available space (as long as the width is not computed as "auto").

Or as kukkuz suggests, you could put the auto right margin on the `<nav>` element instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `display: flex;` on the `.header` already, maybe it is as simple as using `justify-content` there, too…

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: white;
}

/*
---------------------------
----------Flexbox----------
---------------------------
*/

.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.menubtn {
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
    align-self: center;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.nav {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    transition: .5s;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.closebtn {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-top: 3em;
}



/*
---------------------------
--------Responsive---------
---------------------------
*/

@media (min-width: 640px) {

    .closebtn {
        display: none;
    }

    .menubtn {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav {
        transition: 0;
        background: none;
        color: #000;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        position: static;
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
  

    .nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <p class="menubtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</p>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                        <li class="nav-item closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">Termékek</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">Kapcsolat</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">Szállítás</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1 class="logo">Mineral Fever</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `margin-right: auto` to the `nav` element - see demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: white;
}


/*
---------------------------
----------Flexbox----------
---------------------------
*/

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 80px;
}

.menubtn {
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  align-self: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

nav {
  margin-right: auto; /* added */
}

.nav {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  transition: .5s;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.closebtn {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
  margin-top: 3em;
}


/*
---------------------------
--------Responsive---------
---------------------------
*/

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .closebtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .menubtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    transition: 0;
    background: none;
    color: #000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <p class="menubtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</p>
      <nav>
        <ul id="nav" class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</li>
          <li class="nav-item">Termékek</li>
          <li class="nav-item">Kapcsolat</li>
          <li class="nav-item">Szállítás</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1 class="logo">Mineral Fever</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```